# MS CRM 365(9.0) Call On Demand Workflow from Form Ribbon Button

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, crm-ribbon-workbench

Solution Used: 
 https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/132235-create-a-workflow-short-cut-ribbon-button-no-code

I'm able to run workflow but getting below error:

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: workflow With Id =
>   xx2066x5-fd6a-e811-a958-000d3af06ac5 Does Not Exist

I double-checked Workflow Id is right one. So what is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the incorrect GUID of workflow to run. In above solution steps are different to get GUID to run workflow.

Get correct workflow ID using below steps.

- On Form Ribbon click on Run Workflow button
- Choose Workflow record and inspect html to get correct GUID. See below screen shot.

[image]